# how to rise usability of this code?

Tags: php, css, html, codeigniter

i have 5 or more method as the following method.
i hope to help me to write one method or two to reduce code and increase usability of my code:

```
public function index() {
    $this -> load -> view('header');
    $this -> load -> view('navigation');
    $this -> load -> view('default_form');
    $this -> load -> view('footer');
}

public function view_courses() {
    $this -> load -> view('header');
    $this -> load -> view('navigation');
    $this -> load -> view('courses');
    $this -> load -> view('footer');
}

public function view_classrooms() {
    $this -> load -> view('header');
    $this -> load -> view('navigation');
    $this -> load -> view('classroom');
    $this -> load -> view('footer');
}
```

Comment: Try to be more clear about what you really want to achieve, detail your need.

Comment: Look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266827/creating-a-master-template-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could go about this, and which one makes sense (if any at all) is entirely up to personal opinion.  (My PHP is very rusty and I've never used CodeIgniter, so this may not be syntactically accurate.  Consider it a pseudo-code demonstration.)

One approach might be to create smaller "helper" functions which just delegate the functionality a little bit.  Something like this:

```
public function view_classrooms() {
    $this -> view_header_and_navigation();
    $this -> load -> view('classroom');
    $this -> view_footer();
}

private function view_header_and_navigation() {
    $this -> load -> view('header');
    $this -> load -> view('navigation');
}

private function view_footer() {
    $this -> load -> view('footer');
}
```

The returns on that are quickly diminishing in this case, though.  It's really suited toward refactoring larger pieces of functionality.

Another approach might be to make one generic function:

```
public function view_something($content) {
    $this -> load -> view('header');
    $this -> load -> view('navigation');
    $this -> load -> view($content);
    $this -> load -> view('footer');
}
```

Of course here the trade-off is that you'd need to know the implementation details when calling the function, if only a little bit.  To address that you might create delegate functions to go with it:

```
public function view_courses() {
    $this -> view_something('courses');
}
```

But, again, the returns can start to diminish quickly.

There's really nothing *inherently* wrong with the approach you currently have.  (Unless this is just a small example and the problem is on a much larger scale.)  Each view is being explicitly constructed of its parts.  Sure, those parts are often repeated.  But aside from code aesthetics does this represent an actual problem?  Is this code changing often that there is a lot of repeated work?  If that's the case, consider the repeated work carefully when deciding how to refactor, not just the code aesthetics.  Since the repeated work is the actual problem being addressed, not the code.

Comment: Retracted my close vote. 1+ on an awesome answer. Reversal badge maybe? xD